# Codeigniter 4 BadMethodCallException

Tags: codeigniter-4

I am trying to do a user login and I am getting this error which I can't figure out why. Also, I am not sure whether I can mentioned 1 more question or do I have to separate it on another topic. If I want user to login using either username or email address, how should I do it?

I have uploaded the error message [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DjWm.jpg)

The error seems to be at this line :

```
$user = $model->model('username', $this->request->getVar('username'))
                      ->first();
```

Below are my code:

Controller

```
public function login()
{
    $data = [];
    helper(['form']);
    
    $validation =  \Config\Services::validation();
    
    
    if($this->request->getMethod() == 'post'){
        //validations
        $rules = [
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|validateUser[username, password]'
        ];
        
        $errors = [
            'password' => [
                'validateUser' => 'Username or Password don\'t match'
            ]
        ];
        
        
        if(!$this->validate($rules, $errors)){
            $data['validation'] = $this->validator;
        }else{
            $model = new AccountModel();
            
            $user = $model->model('username', $this->request->getVar('username'))
                          ->first();
                          
            $this->setUserMethod($user);
            return redirect()->to('account');
        }
        
    }
    
    echo view('templates/header', $data);
    echo view('account/login');
    echo view('templates/footer');
}
```

Model

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class AccountModel extends Model{
    
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $allowedFields = [
        'username',
        'email',
        'firstname',
        'lastname',
        'dob',
        'country',
        'contact',
        'password',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'created_by'
    ];
    protected $beforeInsert = ['beforeInsert'];
    protected $beforeUpdate = ['beforeUpdate'];
    
    protected function beforeInsert(array $data) {
        
        $data = $this->passwordHash($data);
        return $data;
        
    }
    
    protected function beforeUpdate(array $data) {
        
        $data = $this->passwordHash($data);
        return $data;
        
    }
    
    protected function passwordHash(array $data){
        if(isset($data['data']['password']))
            $data['data']['password'] = password_hash($data['data']['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        return $data;
    }
    
}

?>
```

Hope someone can help me out here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no AccountModel::model so calling $model->model will result in the error you are seeing... It's kind of very clearly stating that the model method in your AccountModel does not exist. And don't create one called model as it's not a good choice of names and rather meaningless in this context anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have this line trying to call a method called model which does not exist...

This is what you have...

```
$user = $model->model('username', $this->request->getVar('username'))
                          ->first();
```

If you have read the CodeIgniter User Guide, you would see that you really want to be using `where` instead of model... Maybe cause you had model stuck in your head, as that happens sometimes.

```
$user = $model->where('username', $this->request->getVar('username'))->first();
```

See how that flies for you.

Comment: Thank you! Yes it works! As I'm new to this, I still have a lot to learn and figure out.